# How to get linkedIn public profile url from SocialAuth Api in android?

Tags: android

I am using socialauth-4.2.jar and socialauth-android-2.6.jar api to integrate linked in into my android app. Inside ResponseListener Class i m getting information of user who login with linked in. see below code :

```
private final class ResponseListener implements DialogListener {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                        Log.v("", "FIRST NAME : " + adapter.getUserProfile().getFirstName());
            Log.v("", "LAST NAME : " + adapter.getUserProfile().getLastName());
                }
        }
```

But i want to profile URL. How can i get profile url when i used socialauth api ?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell you can't get the public profile url without modifying SocialAuth. It isn't one of the fields queried by the LinkedinImpl Provider.

You can see that from this line

```
private static final String PROFILE_URL = "http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,languages,date-of-birth,picture-url,location:(name))";
```

Answer (score 0):

public class Porofiledata implements SocialAuthListener
    {

```
    @Override
    public void onError(SocialAuthError arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    }

    @Override
    public void onExecute(String provider, Profile t) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         Log.d("Custom-UI", "Receiving Data");
           Profile profileMap = t;
           Log.d("Custom-UI",  "Validate ID         = " + profileMap.getValidatedId());
           Log.d("Custom-UI",  "First Name          = " + profileMap.getFirstName());
           Log.d("Custom-UI",  "Last Name           = " + profileMap.getLastName());
           Log.d("Custom-UI",  "Email               = " + profileMap.getEmail());
           Log.d("Custom-UI",  "Country                  = " + profileMap.getCountry());
           Log.d("Custom-UI",  "Language                 = " + profileMap.getLanguage());
           Log.d("Custom-UI",  "Location                 = " + profileMap.getLocation());
           Log.d("Custom-UI",  "Profile Image URL  = " + profileMap.getProfileImageURL());
    }

}
```

By using this calss we can get the profile data.

Comment: if I want to pass a keyword such as firstname "ABC" to this class and search all profiles with this keyword, how do I set it and use it?

Comment: It seems you want to filter the names and finally want to get the filtered list of values right. The profile will returns an object of values form that object we need to filter the values .rather than getting the values directly(filtered values)